# Importing .txt file using File IO

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a .txt file that has 6 animals listed within it, the aim of the program I am wanting to create is the system to output the relevant noise to the corresponding animal. I have made a similar program but that requires user input, which then outputs the correct noise, or displays *'invalid animal'*. So far I have managed to import the file using a `FileReader` but no `BufferedReader`, at the moment the program just lists the animals, one word per line. I am very new to java and was wondering what the correct/best/most efficient way to go about this is? Would it be an array list or something similar? Any help at all is greatly appreciated as it all helps me. Thanks.

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: @M.leRutte I'm not a student and this isn't a homework problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashMap to store the animals and there noises the key is the animal and the value is its noise. and read the file using bufferedReader and iterate over lines and for each animal get its noise from the hashMap and display the result.

I hope this helped you